# LuaLaTeX, bidi=basic and Tikz awkward behaviour

Tags: tikz-pgf, luatex, bidi

@UlrikeFischer

The following `MWE` demonstrates awkward behaviour of `LuaLaTeX` `bidi=basic` with `Tikz`:

MWE 1 - Normal behaviour

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%:Language
\usepackage[nil]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import=en]{english}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node[
draw=red,
minimum size=1cm,
]
(a) at(0,0){A};
\node[
draw=red,
minimum size=1cm,
anchor=south east,
]
at (a.north west) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following:

[image: MWE1]

When I add to babel options `bidi=basic` I get this:

MWE 2 - Awkward behaviour

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
%:Language
\usepackage[nil, bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import=en]{english}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\node[
draw=red,
minimum size=1cm,
]
(a) at(0,0){A};
\node[
draw=red,
minimum size=1cm,
anchor=south east,
]
at (a.north west) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE2]

Comment: I would switch back to english at the begin of the tikzpicture, graphics and bidi are quite often problematic. Try with `\AddToHook{env/tikzpicture/begin}{\selectlanguage{english} }` (assuming a new latex.

Comment: @Morzen Added to the bug tracker: https://github.com/latex3/babel/issues/121 . Graphics with bidi are complicated because mixing RTL with elements intrinsically LTR, combined in unpredictable ways, is far from trivial.